# Redundant data to comma separated string

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I wish to convert redundant row values into a comma separated string to build a JSON. Here in my example the columns I need to convert to comma separated string is `attrValueId`, `attrValue` and `name`.

Please use the snippet to build the schema

```
CREATE TABLE t
    ([attrId] int, [displayPosition] int, 
     [attrValueId] int, [attrValue] varchar(30),
    name varchar(30), attrName varchar(30),attrType varchar(30),
    isRequired bit);

INSERT INTO t    VALUES
    (1,2,1,'123',NULL,'testattribute','dropdown',0);
INSERT INTO t  VALUES
    (1,2,2,'1234',NULL,'testattribute','dropdown',0);
INSERT INTO t    VALUES
    (3,1,6,'miuu2',NULL,'mult','multi-select',1);
INSERT INTO t VALUES
    (3,1,7,'miuu3396',NULL,'mult','multi-select',1);
```

The table data is like

```
attrId  displayPosition attrValueId attrValue   name    attrName        attrType        isRequired
1       2               1           123         NULL    testattribute   dropdown        0
1       2               2           1234        NULL    testattribute   dropdown        0
3       1               6           miuu2       NULL    mult            multi-select    1
3       1               7           miuu3396    NULL    mult            multi-select    1
```

My required result is

```
  attrId    displayPosition attrValueId attrValue      name      attrName      attrType     isRequired
  1         2               1,2         1234,1234      NULL,NULL testattribute  dropdown     0
  3         1               6,7         miuu2,miuu3396 NULL,NULL mult           multi-select 1
```

My ultimate aim is to construct a JSON string in the format

```
    [
{"attrId":"1","displayPosition":"2","attrValueId":["1,2"],"attrValue":["1234,1234"],"name":["null","null"],"attrName":"testattribute","attrType":"dropdown","isRequired":"0"}
,
{second row goes here}]
```

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: ms sql server 2016

Comment: You can use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) for converting the output to JSON

Comment: any help please

Answer (score 0):

Try using `STRING_AGG()` by doing `GROUP BY` over `attrId` &  `displayPosition`

I have one sample for you.

```
SELECT 
    [attrId]
    ,[displayPosition]
    ,STRING_AGG([attrValueId],',') [attrValueId] 
    ,STRING_AGG(name,',') name 
    ,STRING_AGG([attrValue],',') [attrValue]   
    ,STRING_AGG(attrType,',') attrType, isRequired
 FROM t group by [attrId],[displayPosition],isRequired
```

I have assumed that `[attrId]`,`[displayPosition]`,`isRequired` uniquely represent one row.

For Old SQL Server versions, try `STUFF()`
Check the following threads:
[Group By and STUFF combined result in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41823610/group-by-and-stuff-combined-result-in-sql-server)

[How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server)

Comment: I am using version 2016

Comment: In that case, please follow the following question's thread :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54553172/string-agg-in-sql-server-2016

Comment: Thanks, but i dont want to enable CLR. Can u give any alternate solution

Comment: SELECT attrId, 
string = STUFF(
             (SELECT ',' + attrValue FROM t FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''
           ) 
FROM t GROUP BY attrId,attrName
It gives wrong data

Comment: can u help with this?

Comment: follow : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server